# Variável compartilhada na mesma seção - Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

Há alguma maneira de usar uma `Shared Var` na mesma seção do Relatório Principal onde está o Sub Relatório?

Comment: Seria mais simples passar por parametro

Comment: Já tentou e não deu certo?